# variable in url in android

Tags: java

I have a url that I want to make variable.
it is a search function.
the url is the same only changed one word in the url.
www.blabla.com / android / rssfeed.xml
I want android that can be replaced with a different word.
www.blabla.com / windows / rssfeed.xml.
android and windows must be a variable.
I have the following code in google search only I miss the / rssfeed.xml
can someone tell me how I can do this
and how i can get the variable in the url

```
      case R.id.buttonAmazon:
                  lasturl = "http://storingsoverzicht.nl/";
                  buttonLast.setText("Storingsoverzicht");
                   break;
```

Comment: What have you tried? As far as I know, you can simply concatenate multiple strings to form an URL. `lasturl = "http://storingsoverzicht.nl/" + variable + "/rssfeed.xml";`

Comment: honestly, if you're asking this question, you're nowhere near ready to write Android.  You should start by familiarizing yourself with the basics of programming (I'd recommend starting with Python, it's got a really light learning curve) and then learn Java.

Comment: I come from php.
I know this is in php. Only I did not know in android (java).
I'm new, and sometimes you do not know things immediately.
'm learning java android. thank u voor the info

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
String[] folders = {"android", "windows", "whatever"};
```

And now you can do it like @AmoSluismans already said.

```
lasturl = "http://storingsoverzicht.nl/" + folders[n] + "/rssfeed.xml";
```